# Grails iterating in gsp vs. accessing Map elements

Tags: grails, gsp

Full context:  I'm trying to process multiple files using a grails Application.  The code I will display comes from the post-processing page where it gives information about the files processed.

My initial sense was to use code like this:

```
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Parsed from Excel:</th>
        <th>Uploaded to DS:</th>
        <th>File Name:</th>
        <th>Size:</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <g:each in="${fileContents}" var="item">
            <td>${item}</td>
      </g:each>
        <%-- 
        <td>${fileContents.ExcelRows?.encodeAsHTML()}</td>
        <td>${fileContents.policies?.encodeAsHTML()}</td>
        <td>${fileContents.originalFileName?.encodeAsHTML()}</td>
        <td>${fileContents.Size?.encodeAsHTML()}</td>
        --%>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Now, what I don't understand is why the contents displayed in the `<g:each` loop always reports `key=value` such as `ExcelRows=14` as I have received in one output case.

When I switch comments (note the `<%--` tag being used) it works exactly as expected.  From my "`ExcelRows`" column, I get just "14."  What is wrong with my thinking that the `<g:each` loop should do the same thing?  Intuitively it comes down to `For each item in fileContents
    display item`.

My controller code:

```
def processFile = {
        def uploadedFile = request.getFile('excelFile')
```

//...snipped

```
        def fileContents = [
            ExcelRows:"${ods.numberOfRows}",
            policies:"${ods.numberOfPolicies}",
            originalFileName: "${ods.originalFilename}", 
            Size:"${ods.size}"
            ]

        [fileContents:fileContents]
    }
```

Comment: could u post your controller code? that is returning the model 'fileContents' to your view?!

Comment: @Arthur Neves Added relevant controller code

Comment: so, your object fileContents is a Map not a list! so thats why is displaying key=value

Comment: @Arthur,  How should I iterate a map in gsp-land w/o embedding groovy/Java code?

Comment: how about the second suggestion from Rob Hruska ??  <g:each in="${fileContents.values()}" var="item">
   <td>${item?.encodeAsHTML()}</td>
</g:each>

Comment: Didn't see that til I refreshed, my fault.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When iterating over a map you'll be working with [`Entry`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html)s. Try using:

```
<g:each in="${fileContents}" var="item">
   <td>${item.value?.encodeAsHTML()}</td>
</g:each>
```

Or

```
<g:each in="${fileContents.values()}" var="item">
   <td>${item?.encodeAsHTML()}</td>
</g:each>
```

Comment: Your first example didn't print anything, and the second failed on `${fileContents.values()}`  is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure `fileContents` is actually set (to something non-null) in the view?

Comment: Yeah, I can access elements directly using `<td>${fileContents.ExcelRows?.encodeAsHTML()}</td>`
So I know its there.

Comment: Well that's bizarre. What happens if, in my first example, you replace `${fileContents}` with `${fileContents.entrySet()}`?

Comment: `fileContents` must be null, then.

Comment: I did it to myself.  I altered the controller's return statement which was sending the null object in.  BOTH your lines of code work now.  THANK YOU!!!!