# Send java String Array to .gsp and show all elements

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a typical java string array `String[] token = new String[20]` in a controller.
I want to pass this array to .gsp file, where all the elements in `token` get printed out with a line break.
Wasn't too long before I figured that `<g:each>` should do exactly what needed. However, after attempting multiple options, nothing seems to have worked so far.

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/each.html
This guide shows some examples, however, none of them seem to suit my need, because I need to read an array, not display different domain variables (and I actually tried them without luck).

[Grails iterating in gsp vs. accessing Map elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996043/grails-iterating-in-gsp-vs-accessing-map-elements) This answer did not work

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/How-to-display-the-contents-of-a-string-Array-in-GSP-td1355405.html This at first seemed quite close to what I needed, however that also didn't work.

I've spent hours already on trying different combinations and variations of all those things. Every time it either results in an error or no elements get printed out. I know they are there, because if I ask for them specifically (just for one element), I can see results.

In my controller, I've tried passing the `token` with `render view:'myFancy.gsp', model:['lsOut':token]` and `return [lsOut:token]`. (Even `return ['lsOut':token]` just to be sure)

I'm out of ideas. Any suggestions on what to try next or what I could try again (because maybe I did some mistake)?

Controller:

```
def readContents() 
{
    String s = new RunSshCommand().execute() {
        host = params.ServerAddress
        username = params.Username
        password = params.Password
        command = "ls -m Funk"
        }

    String[] token = new String[20]
    token = s.split(",")
    //render view:'readContents.gsp', model:['i':token]
    return [lsOut:token]
}
```

GSP file

```
    <ul>
        <g:each in="${token}" var="lsOut">
            <td>${lsOut.value?.encodeAsHTML()}</td>
        </g:each>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Can you also add what you have tried latest in the controller and gsp exactly?

Comment: Sure, added the latest code. As you can see I was pretty desperate already and was trying basically anything. I'm not sure how much that helps though, because ideally I should show everything that I've tried, but I can't simply remember all my attempts anymore. And before anyone says that I shouldn't parse ls output - yes, I know, but server doesn't support SSHFS (at least can't count on it), so I'm open to suggestions on that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GSP file needs to get the list named `lsOut` in the model and iterate on all the elements. Note that with `<td>` all elements will appear in a single table row. You must use HTML separator  `<li>` in order to display the elements on multiple lines in the `<ul>` list:

```
<ul>
    <g:each in="${lsOut}" var="it">
        <li>${it.encodeAsHTML()}</li>
    </g:each>
</ul>
```

Comment: The `<td>` was basically just a leftover from previous attempt. Same with `<ul>` as the result doesn't necessarily have to be in that list. Already tested both in `<ul>` using `<li>` and without `<ui>` by putting `${it.encodeAsHTML()}` between `<div>` tags, worked beautifully both times. Thanks a lot!